# How to get the first n characters of a string but ending with a whole word

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a string and want to get the first n characters of this string but ends with a whole word.

```
DECLARE @text VARCHAR(MAX) = '123 4056 78789 abcdefg 2222222222 3333 444 55555'
        ,@length INT = 23
```

I have written this query so far:

```
REVERSE(STUFF(REVERSE(LEFT(@text, @length)), 1, CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(LEFT(@text, @length))),''))
```

The output for `@length = 23` is `123 4056 78789 abcdefg`

But for `@length = 22` is `123 4056 78789` which is not correct and should be still `123 4056 78789 abcdefg`

Thanks!

**EDIT**

Just to clarify my question:

From `@length = 22` till `@length = 32` I should get `123 4056 78789 abcdefg`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your requirements correctly, I think you want the following:

```
WITH x AS (
    SELECT '123 4056 78789 abcdefg 2222222222 3333 444 55555' AS [text], 22 AS [length]
)
SELECT LEFT([text], LEN([text]) - CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE([text]), LEN([text]) - [length]))
  FROM x;
```

(I put everything into the `WITH` clause just so I can refer to the column names instead of plugging in your values.)

[Please see SQL Fiddle demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/42386). I tested it with values of 22 and 32 for length.

**UPDATE** per comments below:

```
WITH x AS (
    SELECT '123 4056 78789 abcdefg 2222222222 3333 444 55555' AS [text], 22 AS [length]
)
SELECT LEFT([text], LEN([text]) - CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE([text]) + ' ', LEN([text]) - [length]) + 1)
  FROM x;
```

Comment: That's the one I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Just to be pedantic! :) For @length with a lower value than the position of the first space (e.g. 2) your query returns the entire string, whereas the requirement as given would be that it should return an empty string... So to modify slightly... `SELECT LEFT(@text, LEN(@text) - CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(@text) + ' ', LEN(@text) - @length) + 1);`

Comment: @colmde, thank you for the correction - I've updated the answer per your comments.

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand your requirements.

What you need to do is to find the first space after the length, then return all the characters up until that point.

Try this:

```
SELECT LEFT(@text + ' ',CHARINDEX(' ',@text,@length))
```

Comment: The proper expression would be:  `SELECT LEFT(@text + ' ', CHARINDEX(' ', @text, @length))`.  This guarantees that the query will not fail on shorter strings.

Comment: Thanks but if you use @length = 24 you get '123 4056 78789 abcdefg 2222222222' although you still should get '123 4056 78789 abcdefg'

Comment: I think the OP wants everything up to the last space before or at the prescribed length, not the first space after.

Comment: Try taking one off the length then i.e SELECT LEFT(@text,CHARINDEX(' ', @text, @length-1))

Comment: Output should be '123 4056 78789 abcdefg' for length between 22 till 32 @WillWainwright

Answer (score 1):

```
select left(@text, case when charindex(' ', @text, @length) = 0 
                        then LEN(@text) 
                        else charindex(' ', @text, @length) - 1 
                   end)
```

Comment: Thanks but if you use @length = 24 you get '123 4056 78789 abcdefg 2222222222' although you still should get '123 4056 78789 abcdefg'

Answer (score 0):

Updated with length.

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(200)='123 4056 78789 abcdefg 2222222222 3333 444 55555',
        @len INT=22
SET @str=Reverse(Substring(@str, 1, @len))
SELECT Reverse(Substring(@str, Patindex('%[a-z]%', @str), @len))
```

Without length

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(200)='123 4056 78789 abcdefg 2222222222 3333 444 55555'
set @str=REVERSE(@str)
SELECT reverse(Substring(@str, 
             Patindex('%[a-z]%',@str), 
             Charindex(' ', @str, Patindex('%[a-z]%',@str) )-Patindex('%[a-z]%',@str)))
```

Comment: You are not using length I mentioned in my question. Also I am not looking for just [a-z]. This text can be anything. Mix of letters, numbers, special characters and so on. Output for length between 22 to 32 should be '123 4056 78789 abcdefg' which is different than urs.

Comment: I have updated with length, for your definition of "text can be anything", i have reversed the string and find the character's position thus giving me the last char of the string(which can be of anything).One question i have is can the word end with a number?

Comment: No can be anything. Also if you run your query you are eliminating 'g' at the end.

Comment: Thanks mate but this is not what I am looking for. As I said before this text can be anything. Try 'rt3 tyu 78y789 abcdefg 222jj2222222 3333  rftghrtgrt 444 55555' with the length of 29. Your query returns 'rt3 tyu 78y789 abcdefg 222jj' which is not the right answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
DECLARE @text VARCHAR(MAX) = '123 4056 78789 abcdefg 2222222222 3333 444 55555'
        ,@length INT = 23

SELECT SUBSTRING(REPLACE(RTRIM(LTRIM(@text)),' ',''),1,@length) AS [Text Output]
```

I included the `RTRIM()` and `LTRIM()` to remove any white spaces before and after the string. Then Replace all spaces in the string. Finally get the sub-string of the length (whatever @length is set to).

Comment: Please try to run and see the result. It's not what I want. Output should be '123 4056 78789 abcdefg' for length between 22 till 32